# How to hide elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use a 3rd party shopping module for this site and hence i cannot tinker with the sourcecode of this module.

Everthing works fine but here is my issue.
On the checkout option the summary contains field which are redundant and i want to hide this fields.

```
Discount:  GBP £0.00
Sub total: GBP £90.00
Shipping:  GBP £10.00
Handling:  GBP £0.00
Total:     GBP £100.00
```

As you see above only 3 fields have values. I want to use Javascript and hide the fields which do not have any values like "Discount", "Shipping" and "Handling".

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErtpL/1) to my code

Here is my code

```
<div class="CartTotalAmountContainer">
    <div class=" TotalSalesOrderDetailDiscountAmount">
        <div>
            <label> <span>Discount:</span> 
            </label>
        </div>  <span>GBP £0.00</span>

    </div>
    <div class="SubTotalAmount">
        <div>
            <label> <span>Sub total:</span> 
            </label>
        </div>  <span>GBP £90.00</span>

    </div>
    <div class="TotalShippingAmount">
        <div>
            <label> <span>Shipping:</span> 
            </label>
        </div>  <span>GBP £10.00</span>

    </div>
    <div class="TotalHandlingAmount">
        <div>
            <label> <span>Handling:</span> 
            </label>
        </div>  <span>GBP £0.00</span>

    </div>
    <div class="TotalAmount">
        <div class="dnnLabel">
            <label> <span>Total:</span> 
            </label>
        </div>  <span>GBP £100.00</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

No my logic is i can access the topcontainer of the elements by using

```
var X= document.getElementsByClassName("CartTotalAmountContainer");
```

but how do i access the data inside the individual spans and make the style="display:none" for their parent divs.

Comment: you can't put a class on this fields and hide with CSS?

Comment: No. The HTML is generaes dynamically. It has to hide the divs conditionally. Only if the amount is 0.00 or else display the div

Comment: If you create the list dynamically, in your loop, you can add a class if there is no value.

Comment: it is a bit easier to select elements and their children in [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) but if you have to use vanilla javascript I think you'll have to use [nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: is Opencart? WooCommerce? Magento?

Comment: If you were using jQuery you could do it pretty easily like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7PRD/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `.querySelector`:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".CartTotalAmountContainer > div > span");

for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].innerHTML == "GBP £0.00") {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

[Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/ErtpL/3/)

And here's some reading for ya: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: WOnderful... I just changed the line inside the loop to this "
        x[i].parentNode.style.display = "none";" and it worked as i wanted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete native JS solution which works in IE8 and below: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/giri_jeedigunta/46QyE/

    `var outerDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        cartContainer, i,
        j,
        cartInnerContent;
    // Since getElementsByclassName doesnt work in IE8:
    for(i = 0; i < outerDiv.length; i++) {
        if(outerDiv[i].className === 'CartTotalAmountContainer') {
            cartContainer = outerDiv[i];
            cartInnerContent = cartContainer.getElementsByTagName('div');
            break;
        }
    }`

```
// Queryselector have limitations in IE8 and below
for(j = 0; j < cartInnerContent.length; j++) {
    if(typeof cartInnerContent[j].getElementsByTagName('span')[1] !== 'undefined') {
        var spanContent = cartInnerContent[j].getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML, 
            priceSplit = spanContent.split('£')[1].split('.')[0];
            console.log(priceSplit);

        if(parseInt(priceSplit) === 0) {
            cartInnerContent[j].style.display = 'none';
        }

    }
}
```